# Gmail personal email shows as “work” account

Tags: samsung, security, google-account, accounts

On the settings/accounts & backup/accounts page, myphone lists my gmail.com account as a “work account”.

I do not have a separate work profile.

The gmail work account is listed in addition the google account & email. It is alongside my actual corporate work account with the same swing badge icon.

I accepted mdm for the corporate account (an office 365 based account), which confers admin rights over the phone.

A separate exchange active sync is also present for the corporate account.

I should be able to remove the corporate account & this will remove the content (contacts, calendars, emails) but I am very nervous about any effort to remove the work gmail account.

- Could anyone confirm what effect this might have if I try to remove the “work” gmail?
- How can I tell which organisation actually owns this “work” gmail account?
  (All references I find are for workspace corporate gmail accounts & work profiles but this is a personal gmail.com so I haven’t found assistance there)

Eg, has a malicious app gained control of the account? (No current evidence of that, but who knows….)

I will discuss with the sysadmin responsible for my corporate account - could it just be a side effect of enabling o365 corporate stuff?

My section of company is being demerged/transferred very soon so I like to resolve before someone accidentally wipes my entire phone….

Thanks the reading

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps. Possibly only to expand on your question as opposed to answer it directly.

I have 4 email addresses

I have a work profile with 1 gmail email and it is a parallel gmail app. In my personal gmail app (below) i see my 2 personal gmail emails (blacked out) and the only hint of the work one is the link in red.

[image: gmail]

Of interest to you is my fourth, Microsoft outlook email account with msn.com. For no logical reason under accounts one entry has it labeled as a work account.

[image: msn account]

*If* this is what you see then i believe you have nothing to fear, it is out of reach of my employer. This might not be what you see. I am very unsure why mine has a work label.

When you say

> my gmail.com account as a “work account"

Do you mean it is a personal one?

Comment: yes, it is my personal email additionally tagged as a "work account" that I am unsure of. I don't have a separate work profile to both personal & work emails are shown, unlike your switch profile.   In essence I think your situation is the same though - your personal email is listed as a work account. I am hoping this is just to give the workplace authority to remotely wipe the device and that this will not affect the local content when the phone is separated from the workplace cleanly.

Comment: If it is _exactly_ the same as my Microsoft account, appearing twice with those icons and all, i suspect it is just a UI bug. Perhaps add a screenshot